# Merge Multiple Text Features into One

Tags: qgis-2.18

I’m looking for the best way to merge text features into one and wrap the text.

Here is what I would like to do in as few steps as possible:

```
• Select features to be joined
• Merge features attributes (text) (I've been using concatenate)
• Replace "," with "]" since concatenate adds commas ("]" is set to wrap text)
• Set text order ex: 175]+7.5].75”
• Delete duplicate features
```

There are thousands of features for this to be done so it gets a little tedious to merge the features, add brackets for wrapping and then delete the duplicates. Would there be a way to do this all in one step? Would this be possible to do with the Processing Modeler or Python? (I'm not very fluent with either yet)

Here is an example of how I've been merging features.

[image]

Select features to be merged

[image]

Concatenate features + replace commas with brackets + set proper order

[image]

Then delete the duplicates

[image]

Comment: I'm using QGIS 2.18.13